# Client server program in javascript using npm-net module

Tags: javascript, npm, client-server

I've a simple code `echo_server.js`. Its a server that will simply echo back whatever text is sent by the connected client.

```
var net=require('net');
var server=net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    socket.write('server reply '+data);
  });
});
server.listen(8888);
```

I'll run this code as `$ node echo_server.js`. This code creates a socket on port 8888. From a new terminal I can connect to this server using this command `$ telnet localhost 8888`. And then I'll get the same texts as replies as if echoed by the server.

Programs works absolutely fine on Linux but misbehaves on Windows. It echoes back keys with every key stroke. I know node is platform independent. Is there something wrong with `telnet` client.

On ubuntu `netstat -an | grep 8888` shows that server is up and running, listening on port 8888.But on Windows, its apparent on using `netstat -an` that port 8888 is still not up.

For windows environment I'm using my company's laptop. Is there something that they've disabled? What should I do?

Complete project is [here](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/client-app)

Comment: I'm confused. You say that on WIndows every character gets echoed back, but you also say that port 8888 is still not up. If the port isn't up, what's doing the echoing?

Comment: `netstat -an` on windows gives a list of ports. And I didn't find 8888 there.

Comment: Run your node.js code in a debugger, or at least add a console statement, and see if it's receiving anything. The windows telnet might just be providing its own echo.

Comment: Ok sure I'll do that. Code is here https://github.com/tmtanzeel/client-app in case you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I did some research. Read many issues raised on github. Read a lot about `telnet` in both Windows and Linux and found that If you are using a windows telnet client this will surely happen. Use some other telnet client which buffers the keystrokes until you press ENTER like telnet in Linux. Or else you can create a client program which will communicate to the server and not via `telnet`. I'll try to figure out this as soon as possible.